# How do I get an instance of DisplayCutoutCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-9.0-pie, androidx

I'm looking for a way to use `DisplayCutoutCompat` since I want to know the height of the notch of the device to move the layout.

The documentation does not really point out how to get an instance within the onCreate method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using ViewCompat like below

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(yourView, new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            @Override
            public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsetsCompat windowInsetsCompat) {
                //This is where you get DisplayCutoutCompat
                windowInsetsCompat.getDisplayCutout();
                return windowInsetsCompat;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I totally forgot to write that answer myself. In the end I used the same callback, but I used simply the property `insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();` to get the hight.

Comment: `insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();` gives you statusBarHeight. If you want exact cutout height, you will have to get it from `windowInsetsCompat.getDisplayCutout().getSafeInsetTop();`. Cutout height may be less than or equal to `insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();`